# Username/password authentication for Azure App Service: Mobile

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm following this tutorial in order to provide username/password authentication from my mobile server: http://www.newventuresoftware.com/blog/custom-authentication-with-azure-mobile-apps

My server-side code is this, using the Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Login NuGet package:

```
private JwtSecurityToken GetAuthenticationTokenForUser(string username)
{
    var claims = new[] { new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, username) };
    var signingKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY");
    var issuer = Request.RequestUri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
    return AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken(claims, signingKey, issuer, issuer, TimeSpan.FromHours(24));
}
```

This is generating a weird compiler error. The call to `AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken` is breaking the compiler with the apparently misleading message:

Reference to type 'JwtSecurityToken' claims it is defined in 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt', but it could not be found.

The type `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken` is picked up by Intellisense. Rebuilding the project does not help. This line breaks the build no matter what I do.

Comment: Have you installed the right nuget ref: <package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="4.0.2.205111437" targetFramework="net45" />

Comment: Please find this working sample: https://github.com/Apptracktive/AptkAma/tree/master/AptkAma.Sample/AptkAma.Sample.Backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get this error when updating to the latest nuget version 5.0.0. Reverting back to 4.0.2.2 fixes it.
(referring to the System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt nuget package)